# Dictionary<K,V> always returns the last item

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a problem with retrieving data from a dictionary that I created. The key of the dictionary is an integer and the value is a `List` containing a `Tuple`.

There are 29 items in the dictionary, with integer keys 0 to 28. However, whichever key I use to retrieve data from the dictionary, the item returned is always that of key 28, the last item in the dictionary.

`SignalRoutes` is the name of the dictionary and `SignalRoutes[i]` always returns `SignalRoutes[28]`.

`Item2` of the `Tuple` has the same value as the key, so the results show that when I use a key of 1 (give me the routes for the key of 1) the results returned are those for the key of 28.

I am sure that I haven't loaded the dictionary with 29 copies of the same data.

```
Debug.WriteLine("SignalRoutes count=" + SignalRoutes.Count);
for (int i = 0; i < SignalRoutes.Count; i++)
{
    if (SignalRoutes.ContainsKey(i))
        Debug.WriteLine("dict key found=" + i);
    else
        Debug.WriteLine("dict key NOT found=" + i);

    List< Tuple<int,int,int,int[]> > nsr = SignalRoutes[i];

    if (nsr != null)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < nsr.Count; j++)
        {
            Tuple<int, int, int, int[]> r = nsr[j];
            Debug.WriteLine("route from=" + r.Item2
                + ", to=" + r.Item3
                + ", len=" + r.Item4.Length
                + ", i=" + i
                + ", j=" + j
                + ", route cntr=" + r.Item1
                );
        }
        Debug.WriteLine(String.Empty);
    }
}
```

Here is the start of the output:

```
SignalRoutes count=29
dict key found=0
dict key found=1
route from=28, to=27, len=43, i=1, j=0, route cntr=51
route from=28, to=27, len=43, i=1, j=1, route cntr=52

dict key found=2
route from=28, to=27, len=43, i=2, j=0, route cntr=51
route from=28, to=27, len=43, i=2, j=1, route cntr=52

dict key found=3
route from=28, to=27, len=43, i=3, j=0, route cntr=51
route from=28, to=27, len=43, i=3, j=1, route cntr=52

...
```

Here is the code loading data into the dictionary:

```
Stack<int> route = new Stack<int>();    
List< Tuple<int,int,int,int[]> > routes = new List< Tuple<int,int,int,int[]> >();

foreach (Signal s in SignalList)
{
    ...
    route.Clear();        
    routes.Clear();
    ...
    while ( ... )
    {

        // save route
        if (route.Count > 0)
        {
            int [] routearray = route.ToArray(); // to - from order
            Array.Reverse(routearray); // from - to order
            routecntr++;
            Tuple<int,int,int,int[]> ssroute
                = new Tuple<int,int,int,int[]>(routecntr, s.Number, s2.Number, routearray);
            routes.Add(ssroute); // add route to collection for current signal s

            int ridx = routes.Count -1;
            Debug.WriteLine("fr=" + routes[ridx].Item2
                + ", to=" + routes[ridx].Item3
                + ", len=" + routes[ridx].Item4.Length
                + ", route cntr="+routes[ridx].Item1
                );
         } // if
    } // while

    ...
    Debug.WriteLine("s="+s.Number
        +", no of routes=" + routes.Count
        );
    Debug.WriteLine(String.Empty);

    if (routes.Count == 0)
        SignalRoutes.Add(s.Number, null);
    else
        SignalRoutes.Add(s.Number, routes);
}
```

And here is the data that was loaded:

```
s=0, no of routes=0

fr=1, to=2, len=13, route cntr=0
s=1, no of routes=1

fr=2, to=7, len=41, route cntr=1
fr=2, to=24, len=54, route cntr=2
fr=2, to=12, len=93, route cntr=3
fr=2, to=13, len=100, route cntr=4
fr=2, to=5, len=40, route cntr=5
s=2, no of routes=5

fr=3, to=23, len=16, route cntr=6
fr=3, to=0, len=26, route cntr=7
s=3, no of routes=2

fr=4, to=3, len=14, route cntr=8
s=4, no of routes=1

...
```

Comment: This is a clear symptom that when you fill the dictionary you use always the same instance. Please show the code where you fill the dictionary

Comment: And what will we see...? My guess: "Closing over the loop variable considered harmful"? http://ericlippert.com/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful-part-one/

Comment: @Steve Thanks for your reply. Yes, I do use the same instance, but I call routes.Clear() each time through the loop. So, obviously, there is something happening or not happening that I don't understand.

Comment: Because you are puting the same list in to every slot when you call `Clear()` you are clearing every slot. Replace the `Clear` with a `new List< Tuple<int,int,int,int[]> >`

Comment: @Scott Chamberlain Thanks, Scott. Creating a new List each time did indeed work. In the original code, to get 29 copies of the same data means the the routes instance was used to load the data into the dictionary only after the loop ended,even though the call to dictionary Add is within the loop?

Comment: The `Dictionary` saves `List` (reference to instance) not content of the `List`. So when you have single `List` instance, then any change of content of that `List` instance are visible thru any reference to that instance saved in `Dictionary`.